# Не получается скачать JSON в android приложение

Tags: java, android, json

На сервере есть https://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json (для примера с просторов)

Весь код в Service

Собственно код класса:

```
package tanat.androidtesttask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyService extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

protected String someTask() {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String strJson = "";


    // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json");

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        strJson = buffer.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        strJson += e.getMessage();
    }
    return strJson;
}
}
```

Пытаюсь вытянуть json-строку, но ексепшен срабатывает на строке

```
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

то есть, не вытягивает даже InputStream.

Уже перерыл и stack весь и вообще весь интернет наверное, но никак не могу найти решение. Такой же код встречается много где на просторах и везде вроде как работает.

Ексепшен выдает

```
W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
<куча бреда>
W/System.err: at tanat.androidtesttask.MyService.someTask(MyService.java:34)
W/System.err: at 
tanat.androidtesttask.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
```

Похоже что ругается на

```
urlConnection.connect();
```

Помогите пожалуйста, спасибо.

Comment: `но ексепшен срабатывает` - что говорит?

Comment: W/System.err: at tanat.androidtesttask.MyService.someTask(MyService.java:34)

Похоже что ругается на
urlConnection.connect();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ошибке вы пытаетесь обратиться к серверу в главном потоке. Так запрещено.

Можно использовать `AsyncTask`.

```
private class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

          \\здесь выполняйте обращение к серверу

            return strJson;\\возврат строки с json

        }


        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String answer) {
         \\здесь сделайте необходимое с полученной строкой
            Log.d(“tag”, answer)
        }

    }
```

Запускать так

```
new GetTask().execute();
```

Comment: А если задача в том что б использовать Service?

Comment: А даже если так как сделать что б в textView результат шел уже после того как код прошёл цикл а не сразу же возвращалась пустая строка?

Comment: @PavelZlotarenchuk ну если хочется, то можно попробовать IntentService. Это тоже сервис, но для своей работы он создаст отдельный поток, что в теории должно тоже решить проблему